# Check if db connection is closed - php

Tags: php, sql

Db connectivity is handled by an include.

I want to run this command:
mysql_close($con);

Only if we currently have a connection.  Something like isset()?

Thanks Hamad

Answer (score 8):

```
is_resource($con)
```

gives `false` if the connection is closed.

Comment: You can add `&& get_resource_type($con) === 'mysql link'` to make sure is a mysql link resource.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `mysql_ping($con);`

Depending on your PHP version, the older ones would reopen the connection if it was closed automatically. It shouldn't do that in PHP5

Comment: From the Manual: `Warning
This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more information. Alternatives to this function include:
mysqli_ping()`

Answer (score 0):

You can test the connection by doing a simple [`mysql_ping`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-ping.php), which will re-open the connection if it's closed.

Answer (score 0):

I give the credit to @Artefacto, but I ran into a problem where my `$con` wasn't set and I received a message such as:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: con in...
```

so I changed to:

```
if ( is_resource($con)) {
     mysqli_close($con);
}
```

Please note that the `mysql_ping($con)` is now Deprecated.